# doctrine mongodb odm query group by

Tags: sql, mongodb, doctrine-odm

i have 3 collections and i want to perform query which is similar to sql query like

```
SELECT fp.userId, fp.orderId, productId, fp.request_Payment_ChargeTotal, 
fp.createdOn, u.referrerSite, COUNT(*), 
sum( fp.request_Payment_ChargeTotal ) AS total 
FROM `firstdata_payment_webservice` fp, userlicenses ul, users u 
WHERE u.userId = ul.userId
AND fp.response_TransactionResult = 'APPROVED' 
AND fp.request_Payment_ChargeTotal > 0 
AND ul.orderId = fp.orderId AND fp.createdOn 
BETWEEN cast( '2011-09-10' AS DATETIME ) 
AND cast( '2011-09-20' AS DATETIME )
GROUP BY u.referrerSite, productId WITH ROLLUP
```

How can i do similar operation in doctrine mongodb odm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, applying "JOIN" is not the intent of MongoDB. So you have to structure your data differently.

`db.users`

- id
- name
- licences (stored as Hash type)

`db.orders`

- id
- created_on (Datetime type)
- processed_on (Datetime type)
- user_id (may be a DBRef or an ObjectId type)
- products (stored as an Array type, containing objects)
- transaction (stored as Hash type, with info like datetime, webservice type and other stuff)

With MapReduce, you can count other stuff by querying the orders table.
And if you need data on the customers, do it in another query, using an array of users ObjectIds you are looking for.